# Customizing Letters In Headings

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was wondering if there is a way to customize letters in Headers. For Example in the image I am trying to reproduce:

[image]

For the MWE I only provide: (sorry!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
\lhead{PROLOGUE}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For a quick solution, you can borrow `\mathbb{}` from `amssymb`: `$\mathbb{PROLOGUE}$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{contour}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{white}{\contour*{black}{PROLOGUE}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for your comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{contour}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\textcolor{white}{\contour*{blue}{\huge\bfseries PROLOGUE}}}%
\begin{document}
\textcolor{white}{\contour*{black}{PROLOGUE}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to run \fancyhead[L]{\textcolor{white}{\contour*{blue}{\huge {\bf PROLOGUE}}}} in my program above but it gets kickout of the header and into the text. Any advice how to proceed?

Comment: yes now I have this working. Very helpful!